Ananke Website Theme in Hugo, failed to load modules
just want to ask about this problem, im having a hard time setting up my local host. can anyone know how to fix this? whenever i type ./hugo server, i receive this error although go.mod file is exactly in that same directory. but the error says they cant file the file go.mod. Thanks for the response.
enter image description here
i tried changing the theme to ananke, i followed what data professor is doing but its not working on me.

You would benefit from learning how to create a simple hugo site, then adding themes and modules once you master the basics.

I have the latest Hugo server and have created a new site. I downloaded the Ananke theme following the instructions. I had to to set the line theme="ananke" in the config.toml and comment out the line:
theme = ["github.com/theNewDynamic/gohugo-theme-ananke"] 

when running using the command
hugo server --source=themes/ananke/exampleSite/ themesDir=../.. 

